# Tensor shape mismatch error in PyTorch on MNIST dataset, but no error on synthetic data

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement a Deep Learning paper (https://github.com/kiankd/corel2019) and having a weird error when supplying real data (MNIST) to it, but no error when using the same synthetic data as the authors used. 
The error happens in this function:

```
def get_armask(shape, labels, device=None):
    mask = torch.zeros(shape).to(device)
    arr = torch.arange(0, shape[0]).long().to(device)
    mask[arr, labels] = -1.
    return mask
```

More specifically this line:

```
mask[arr, labels] = -1.
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeError: The shape of the mask [500] at index 0 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [500, 10] at index 1
```

The weird thing is, that if I use the synthetic data, there is no error and it works perfectly. If I print out the shapes, I get the following (both with synthetic data and with MNIST):

```
mask torch.Size([500, 10])
arr torch.Size([500])
labels torch.Size([500])
```

The code used to generate the synthetic data is the following:

```
X_data = (torch.rand(N_samples, D_input) * 10.).to(device)
labels = torch.LongTensor([i % N_classes for i in range(N_samples)]).to(device)
```

While the code to load MNIST is this:

```
train_images = mnist.train_images()
X_data_all = train_images.reshape((train_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1] * train_images.shape[2]))
X_data = torch.tensor(X_data_all[:500,:]).to(device)
X_data = X_data.type(torch.FloatTensor)

labels = torch.tensor(mnist.train_labels()[:500]).to(device)
```

get_armask is used the following way:

```
def forward(self, predictions, labels):
    mask = get_armask(predictions.shape, labels, device=self.device)

    # make the attractor and repulsor, mask them!
    attraction_tensor = mask * predictions
    repulsion_tensor = (mask + 1) * predictions

    # now, apply the special cosine-COREL rules, taking the argmax and squaring the repulsion
    repulsion_tensor, _ = repulsion_tensor.max(dim=1)
    repulsion_tensor = repulsion_tensor ** 2

    return arloss(attraction_tensor, repulsion_tensor, self.lam)
```

The actual error seems to be different from what is in the error message, but I have no idea where to look. I tried a few things, like changing the learning rate, normalizing the MNIST data to be more or less in the same range as the test data but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you show how you use the `get_armask` function ?

Comment: I added the relevant function, but if you need more context go to the GitHub link, the whole project is there, I didn't modify much besides what I already posted.

Comment: Is your  two `X_data` of the same size?  And what is the actual value of  your `shape` parameter when passed in `get_armask` function?

Answer (score 0):

After exchanging some emails with the author of the paper we figured out what is the problem. The labels were type of Byte instead of Long, that caused the error. The error message is very misleading, the actual problem has nothing to do with the sizes...